# How solve the axis label for chord diagram in R?

Tags: r, axis-labels, chord-diagram

Recently I made some chord diagrams, one part of the diagram was column variables and other part of diagram was rows. i made several pictures using the code below, never had any problems but i don't know why i could not use in this data.

data i am using

```
data = structure(list(Sample = c("PP", "PP:PE", "PE", "PES", "PS", "Rayon", 
"Acrylic", "Resin", "Nylon", "PTFE", "PVA"), Bottom = c(110.625641, 
2.446153846, 14.58461538, 47.83589744, 1.774358974, 14.61538462, 
48.47692308, 0, 0, 0, 0), Surface = c(71.0974359, 4.112820513, 
5.487179487, 36.01025641, 1.087179487, 3.620512821, 30.62564103, 
0, 3.241025641, 0, 1.128205128)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

The code I used was;

```
data = read.csv(file.choose(), row.names = 1)


data <- as.matrix(data)


col = c( 'PP' = "#8601af", 'PP:PE'  = "blue", 'PE' = "Cyan", 'PES' = "springgreen", 'PS' = "yellow", 'Rayon' = "darkorange", 'Acrylic' = "red", 'Resin' = "darkslateblue", 'Nylon' = "deepskyblue1", 'PTFE' = "darkgreen", 'PVA' = "orchid1", 'Bottom' = "grey 35", 'Surface' = "grey 71")

chordDiagram(data, grid.col = col, annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks = 1)

circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 2, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
  circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + 2.5, sector.name, 
              facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5), cex=0.7)
  circos.axis(h = "top", labels.cex = 0.7, major.tick.percentage = 0.2,
              sector.index = sector.name, track.index = 2)
}, bg.border = NA)

dev.copy(jpeg,'S.B-FTIR.tiff', width=8, height=8, units="in", res=500)
dev.off()
```

but my diagram is coming like this[image]

it should pop out the picture below where bottom and surface should be in one side and others parameters in other side.[image]